# QGIS toolbar aligned to the right

Tags: qgis, gui, alignment, internationalization, localisation

Toolbars and menus are aligned to the right in QGIS 3.32.
In version 3.28 it is ok and aligned to the left.

[image]

Comment: Well, what have you tried to resolve the issue? What are you localisation settings, did you change something, etc.

Comment: Try to create a new QGIS profile. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mKTRHL5YLjI

Comment: I have tried a new profile. My localization is English (United States) with Hebrew as an additional language. If I change the User Interface Translation to other languages than American English it aligns ok to the left.

Comment: I have 2 versions installed 3.28 and 3.32.